# How do I Use credentials from AWS Secret Key manager in Jenkins Jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda, jenkins-plugins, aws-secrets-manager

The task is to use the credentials from the AWS secret manager in Jenkins Jobs configure section.

Am using the "AWS Secrets Manager Credentials Provider" plugin in Jenkins, but after integration, I can only use was CLI commands alone.

Here while integrating this plugin in cloud bees video I noticed that we need to enter the AWS secret key ID and Access key sysconfig file under JAVA_OPTIONS.

But I couldn't find the sysconfig file in my Jenkins.

Can someone help here on this?

Please let me what is the proper way to integrate AWS Secret key manager with Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

- Try using ec2 instance profile with necessary permissions as mentioned in the [plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-secrets-manager-credentials-provider/#documentation), attach it with ec2 instance in which jenkins is hosted.
- Goto   Manage jenkins -> configure system ->  AWS Secrets Manager Credentials Provider (leave credentail provider as default) select the aws region

This worked for me.